# Fetch specific values from nested tuples in a list

Tags: python, list, filter, tuples

I have a nested tuple inside list as bellow:

```py
x = [(('subject', 'to'), 18), (('subject', 'and'), 5), (('subject', 'of'), 4), (('subject', 'the'), 3), (('subject', 'that'), 2), (('subject', 'owing'), 2), (('subject', 'making'), 2)]
```

I need a list of 2nd value (index 1) of inner tuples. How do i list it?

what i need as output:

```py
['to','and','of','the','that','owing','making']
```

in that specific order

This is what i tried

```py
x[0][0][1]
```

my output

```py
to
```

Comment: Simply iterate and fetch the value at the index you need. Both `list` and `tuple` support indexing. Try and post again if you need help with something else. Voting to close this now

Comment: This looks like your homework. Can I ask what you have tried to solve this? Simply looking up tuples and list comprehensions should show you the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using List comprehension and variable unpacking:

```
newList = [j for (i, j), index in x]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `map` to do this:

```
x = list(map(lambda el: el[0][1],x))
print(x)
```

Result:

```
['to', 'and', 'of', 'the', 'that', 'owing', 'making']
```